# Adding color to the footnote mark in Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, color

I'd like to change the color of a footnote, both the text and the mark in a presentation I'm preparing using beamer. The example I give below works in article but not in beamer...any ideas why not?

```
%\documentclass{article} %works.
\documentclass{beamer}   %does not work.
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{red}\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Thus we expand every part of the solution, $u, U, V$, and $\lambda$ 
as an asymptotic series\footnote{\color{red}This is 
actually a lie\ldots but don't tell anyone}:
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the beamer class command `\setbeamercolor` for coloring footnotes and footnote marks, for example:

```
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds.  I actually found that the second command changed both the footnote mark and text color.  Did you find a way to change both independently?

Comment: @Matthew: do you mean the first command? In my opinion it's a good default behavior of the first command to change also the mark color (at least it does it in the footer). Independently - no problem, firstly set text color and afterwards mark color to a different one.

Comment: OMM if I do `\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=green}\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}` I get *both* footnote mark and text in red, not a mark in red and text in green as I would expect.  The line separating main text from the footnote is green, though.

Comment: The footnote text is red by default.  More testing: `\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=green}` make the footnote *rule* blue, the foonote *mark* green, but the footnote *text* remains red.

Comment: Now I get it.  I was testing on the OP's sample code, which put `\color{red}` into the footnote argument.  Never mind!

Comment: That explains it. I did not see this possibility because I've deleted this `\color{red}` at first.

Comment: @Yossi: no problem. I've edited.