# Add text around footnote mark in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I've been trying to change the behavior of the footnotes in beamer. I can change the "footnote" template fine, but I'm having trouble changing the marker in both places. Ideally, I'd like to have flexible control, but here's a simple example.

If I want to use `[1]` instead of `^1`. After seeing [how-do-i-change-footnote-font-size-in-beamer-presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21741/how-do-i-change-footnote-font-size-in-beamer-presentation), this is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\insertfootnotemark{#1}}{\insertfootnotemark{[#1]}}{}{}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    [\insertfootnotemark] \insertfootnotetext
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Footnote test}
    Hello World.\footnote{Hello Back}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but the output from pdflatex didn't seem to change. I've seen lots of folks messing with the color (see [adding-color-to-the-footnote-mark-in-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6147/adding-color-to-the-footnote-mark-in-beamer)), but not too much with the style from what I've looked at.

Comment: It would be great if you'd pick a 'more memorable' user name: these `userXXXX` ones are okay to start with, but keeping a track of who is who gets difficult!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were not far off, but `beamer` is not very flexible about some things (mainly ones which are discouraged in the manual). Here, there are a couple of patches needed

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\@textsuperscript}{\@makefnmark@aux}{}{}
\newcommand*{\@makefnmark@aux}[1]{[#1]}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \leavevmode \insertfootnotemark~\insertfootnotetext
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Footnote test}
    Hello World.\footnote{Hello Back}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The idea is first to remove the `\@textsuperscript` from `\@makefnmark`, then to also deal with the fact that we then need a space where the footnote is actually printed. That needs a `\leavevmode`, which really should be in the underlying code I guess, but clearly is not!