# beamer: Change Footnote Color

Tags: beamer, footnotes

- I have a beamer presentation with a complex color scheme.
- In order to improve readability I need to change the color of the footnote.
- Problem is, that I need to change the color for each "part" (see screenshot) of a footnote:

**I want to *independently* change the color of the following 4 "parts":**

1. Footnote mark in the text.
2. Footnote mark in the footnote.
3. Footnote text (`--> \textcolor{blue}{Footnote text}` works locally.).
4. Line that separates footnote from the text.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? At the moment I use a combination of `\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=white}`, `\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=.}` and `\footnote{\textcolor{color}{Text}}`.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}   

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6147
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test\footnote{Test}.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

### Related

- [Making footnote marks in beamer use the surrounding color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154819)
- [Adding color to the footnote mark in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6147)

Comment: Probably you can use `\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{<color>}{\oldfootnoterule}}` to change the color of the separating line.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! I will try it tomorrow. You can provide a (partial) answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question just asked about individually coloring components of footnotes without including an actual color scheme, the following is just a guess:

With you can change the color of the separating line: `\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule     \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{<color>}{\oldfootnoterule}}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}   

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6147
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=.}

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{green}{\oldfootnoterule}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test{\footnote{Test}}. % \footnote{} needs to be surrounded by {}!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here I have also included a possibility to get 4 different colors for the four elements. I have included some hopefully explanatory annotations in the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}   

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6147
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue} % <----- Color of footnote in footline (will be overwritten later)
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=.}% <----- Color of footnotemark is the same as surrounding text. Causes the footnotemark in the footer to be the color specified in the line before.

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{green}{\oldfootnoterule}}% <----- Color of the separating rule.

\let\oldfootnote\footnote 
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\color{brown}\oldfootnote{\color{red}#1}} % <----- 1: Color of the footnotemark in the text (overwrites the color specified in lines 4+5); 2: Color of the footnote text (overwrites the color specified in line 4)



\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test{\footnote{Test}}. 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Tested it: Works. But it seems to be important, that the `footnote` command is in `{...}` like in `{\footnote{Test}}`. I didn't see it at first!