# Color mismatch between referring/referred to footnotemarks

Tags: color, footnotes

In the example shown, referring is red (as it should), referred+rule is black (it should be red). There is a [similar post for `beamer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500859/beamer-change-footnote-color) that I haven't been able to adapt to this case. There are more packages than needed, too many combinations to figure out the minimal set (I get errors).

```
\documentclass[oneside,fontsize=14pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang]{biblatex}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
%must come last
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\pagecolor{blue}
\afterpage{\pagecolor{white}\color{black}}
\color{red}
%\color{blue}
%\color{white}

\begin{center}

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{green}{\oldfootnoterule}}% <----- Color of the separating rule.

\let\oldfootnote\footnote 
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\color{brown}\oldfootnote{\color{red}#1}} % <----- 1: Color of the footnotemark in the text (overwrites the color specified in lines 4+5); 2: Color of the footnote text (overwrites the color specified in line 4)

\vspace*{\fill}

  {\LARGE
    \textbf{
      TITRE\footnote{\color{red}auteur}
    }
  }

\let\footnoterule\oldfootnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{green}{\oldfootnoterule}}% <----- Color of the separating rule.

\let\footnote\oldfootnote


\vspace*{\fill}

\end{center}


\end{titlepage}


\chapter{Foo}

Foo


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wih the appropriate `\addtokomafont` commands, coloring the footnoteline as well as the footnotelabel can also be done in the `scrbook` class:

More information on that can be found in the KOMA-script documentation:

Section 3.14. Footnotes (page 93)

> You can change the colour of the rule with the footnoterule element
>   using the `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont` commands (see section
>   3.6, page 59).  The default is no change of font or colour.  In order to change the colour, you must also load a colour package like
>   `xcolor`.

Section 3.6. Text Markup (page 61)

> Table 3.2.: Elements whose font style can be changed in
>   `scrbook`,`scrreprt` or `scrartcl` with `\setkomafont` and
>   `\addtokomafont`:
>
> [...]
>
> *`footnote`*: footnote text and marker
>
> *`footnotelabel`*: marker for a footnote; applied in addition to the element `footnote`
>
> *`footnotereference`*: footnote reference in the text
>
> *`footnoterule`*: horizontal rule above the footnotes at the end of the text area

```
\documentclass[oneside,fontsize=14pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addtokomafont{footnoterule}{\color{red}}  % <--- Change color of footnoterule to red
\addtokomafont{footnotelabel}{\color{red}} % <--- Change color of footnotelabel to red
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\color{red}}      % <--- Chang color of footnote text to red
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\pagecolor{blue}
\afterpage{\pagecolor{white}\color{black}}
\color{red}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
  {\LARGE
    \textbf{
      TITRE\footnote{auteur}
    }
  }
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\chapter{Foo}
\addtokomafont{footnoterule}{\color{black}}  % <--- Change color of footnoterule back to black
\addtokomafont{footnotelabel}{\color{black}} % <--- Change color of footnotelabel back to black
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\color{red}}        % <--- Change color of foonote text back to black
Foo \footnote{footnote text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you know what commands to use to replicate this solution, but for figure's legend, specifically for `keyfig` from the `keyfloat` package?

Comment: @Erwann: At the moment I unfortunately don't know. Please ask a new question about this. Like that chances are higher that you will recieve an answer.